# New linux releases on old hypervisor

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, hp-proliant, centos7

I have just bought a Proliant DL360 G5 for learning and testing. It's an old machine but it's enough for me.

When I looking supported operating systems on HP's support pages, I noticed that the supported newest version of the ESXI is 5.x.

I mostly want to use CentOS7 for my tests and for ESXI 5.x, centos 7 is a new operating system, so my question is if I install the ESXI 5.x to my server and use centos7 in it, is it create a problem? Or which one better?

- Use ESXI 6 (Unsupported hardware, supported os)
- Use ESXI 5 (Supported hardware, unsupported os)

I tried both of them and they working for me, probably both solutions are works fine on most situations, but I want to ask this question to learn something. May be there are performance issues.

Comment: CentOS 7 is [supported](http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?deviceCategory=software) on ESXi 5.5 and up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question.

You can use EL7 on your ESXi 5 setup. Be sure to use the "open-vm-tools" package, and you'll be fine.

The hardware is right on the edge of being too old to do much with. However, it will work under both versions of ESXi.

You're not really paying for platform support, so go with the more stable solution; ESXi 5.5 on the older hardware.